# Xcode default snippets (if, for, struct etc.) not showing in autocomplete

Tags: swift, xcode, code-snippets

I am new to Swift and also Xcode. In many tutorials I can see that snippets are really usefull especially for the beginners like me. Unfortunately I can`t use them. When I am typing something, for example` if`or`for`, nothing shows up in the autocomplete section. Or if it does (like for` struct`) when I hit enter it just autocompletes my word.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Instead, it just autocompletes:

[image]

`if`, `for`, etc. doen't even show up in autocomplete.

[image]

I couldn`t find a solution. Any help would be really useful.

I basicly want it to work like this https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-create-code-snippets-in-xcode/#using-xcode-snippets

Comment: Is the availability of your snippet set to `All Scopes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure the proper settings are enabled in Xcode. Go to Xcode -> Preferences (or Settings depending on your version of macOS). Then select the "Text Editing" tab. Then select the "Editing" sub-tab. Ensure the "Suggest completions while typing" option is enabled.

---

While typing in Xcode, begin typing the `struct` keyword but don't press return. You should see the following:

[image]

By selecting the "struct - Struct" choice from the menu, you will end up with desired code block snippet.

This also works when you want to add a code snippet for an `if` statement. Begin by typing `if` (make sure you are entering this in a valid context for an `if` block). Xcode will display appropriate choices:

[image]

Selecting, for example, the "if - If Statement" choice from the menu will leave you with an appropriate snippet:

[image]

Similar snippets are available for various statements such as `for` and `while`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have checked my settings "Suggest completions while typing" option was enabled, I have disabled it and enabled again. Now it works perfectly for "struct" or "func" but for if only the one with dot shows up.

Comment: Found it also for if statement! I needed to scroll down a lot. Thank you once again